# how can properties of transition matrix be applied in the transcation cost of option

Tags: option-pricing, finance-mathematics, mathematics, european-options

I am currently reading the PP BOYLE's article ' Option Replication in Discrete Time with Transaction Costs' written in 1992. Here is one place i couldn't figure out:

[image]

[image]

Where does that $\widehat{p}$ come from? And the $\bar{P} = \begin{pmatrix}
\bar{p_{u}} & \bar{p_{d}}\\
1-\bar{p_{u}} & 1-\bar{p_{d}} 
\end{pmatrix}$

What are $X_{i}$ and $\bar{P}^{i-1}$ ?

Thank you, this is my first time reading academic paper, i tried to google the transition matrix and Markov chains with expectations but the result is not useful.

Comment: Commonly, if the transition matrix has no absorbing states, the limiting distribution of the states is a non-degenerate vector, I think this is $\hat{p}$ in your case - but I am guessing here, as the author did not define it in the paper (I did not find it, at least). Furthermore, the transition matrix is defined in equation 9 of that paper.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know what does the $\bar{P}^{(i-1)}$ mean? Based on the author's definition of $\bar{P}$, can i say that the first column of $\bar{P}^{(i-1)}$ means the probability distribution of $X_{i}$ if $X_{i-1} = ln(u)$ and the second column means the probability distribution of $X_{i}$ if $X_{i-1} = ln(d)$

Comment: I'd argue that this is the matrix $\bar{P}$, as defined in equation 9, raised to the $(i-1)$st power. The interpretation is, roughly, for each column, the probability to being in state $u$ or $d$ after $i-1$ steps given today's state (i.e. first or second column).